# PC Benchmarking for QGIS?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, memory

I've just started working as a GIS technician in a land agency firm. I'm handling large datasets such as historic house sales (~500,000 rows of data per year) and executing heavy duty operations, sub-sequentially putting pressure on a laptop and PC which I've been given to work on. Currently I'm concentrating on 2D visualisation of data but anticipate 3D will come into play further down the line. I'm using QGIS running at version 2.18.5.

**Laptop:**

```
Windows 10, 64 bit

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz 2601Mhz, 2 cores, 4 logical processors

Installed Physical Memory 8.00 GB

Total Available Physical Memory 7.89 GB

Available Physical Memory 3.74 GB

Total Virtual Memory 17.8 GB

Available Virtual Memory 12.7 GB GB

AMD Radeon R7 M370 Graphics Card
```

**PC:**

```
Windows 7, 64 bit

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1225 v5 @ 3.30GHz, 3301 Mhz, 4 cores, 4 logical processors

Installed Physical Memory 8.00 GB

Total Available Physical Memory 7.89 GB

Available Physical Memory 3.85 GB

Total Virtual Memory 15.8 GB

Available Virtual Memory 11.7 GB

(On-board) Intel HD Graphics P530 Graphics Card
```

I've created a stress test with the following shapefile, (EPSG '27700') operating an 'inverse' distance buffer on it (conduct at your own choosing): https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e4wyp13mwbb85d/Benchmark%20Test.zip?dl=0
The shapefile shows all the planning local authorities in the UK, the boundaries of which are made up with many vertices. The test with 'shrink' the polygon features due to a negative buffer setting. The algorithm is the most demanding I've come across hence I've set it up to be my benchmark test.

Both PC and Laptop choke at 95% if distance is set at '-1000' and segments left at '5'. At 2 hours into the algorithium, there was no progress beyond 95% although it took <5 mins to get to 95%.

If the buffer is increased to '-100' the laptop and PC both manage it in good time (min:sec).

**Laptop:** *Time: 5:50*

**PC:**  *Time: 4:30*

The company is planning to get some more powerful hardware for me. The test is purely meant as a comparison and to gain some perspective. If you are running shorter times, or have a good perception for what PC components make QGIS tick faster please let me know.